# Willset does not retain value after initializing

Tags: swift

Hello I have an optional variable which uses the willset functionality. Since its an optional the regular set will not work.  inside the will set I am setting the variable to at least initialize it if the new value is nil. unfortunately, the value after is nil as well any ideas? Thank you

Code:

```
var arrayOfString: [String]? {
   willSet {
      self.arrayOfString = newValue == nil ? [String]() : newValue
   }
}
```

Comment: Why make it optional to begin with? Why not just `var arrayOfString = [String]()`?

Comment: @Hamish thank you for your response, I figured making it as optional since the initial arrayOfString = someValue will be coming from a different  partof the application, because of this, I figured if I initialize first and then if the application does get an array of strings and add it here, I would have used 2 memory spaces when I didnt need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since its an optional the regular set will not work

Not correct. Since it's *not a computed property* `set` will not work.

You need to reread the section about `willSet` and `didSet`. `willSet` is called *before* any value is written to the variable. I.e. whatever you write to the variable inside `willSet` will be overwritten immediately by the assignment that invokes your code.

If you assign `nil` you will overwrite your string array with `nil`.

Simplify by just doing

```
var arrayOfString: [String] = []
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I figured making it as optional since the initial arrayOfString = someValue will be coming from a different partof the application, because of this, I figured if I initialize first and then if the application does get an array of strings and add it here, I would have used 2 memory spaces when I didnt need to?

Comment: @paul590 That's called premature optimization. Don't worry about the memory needed to allocate an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `didSet`:

```
var arrayOfString: [String]? {
    didSet {
        self.arrayOfString = arrayOfString ?? []
    }
}
```

Otherwise the value is immediately overwritten by the original value.

However note that if the variable should never contain an optional, it should be declared as such:

```
var arrayOfString: [String]
```

and the assignment should add the `?? []` when needed.

Otherwise you will have to handle unwrapping everytime you access the value anyway.

Comment: thank you for your response I figured this was the case but I wanted to be 100% certain